# Создать экземпляр внутреннего интерфейса в onAttach(Context context)?

Tags: android

Есть фрагмент Fragment_1, создающий диалог с двумя кнопками OK и CANCEL. В этом фрагменте есть интерфейс и инициализация его экземпляра:

```
private AddingTaskListener addingTaskListener;

public interface AddingTaskListener {
    void onTaskAdding();

    void onTaskAddingCancel();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        addingTaskListener = (AddingTaskListener)context;
        }
      catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement AddingTaskListener");
    }
}
```

Затем эти методы используются для реакции кнопок:

```
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                addingTaskListener.onTaskAdding();
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                addingTaskListener.onTaskAddingCancel();
                dialogInterface.cancel();
            }
```

Есть Fragment_2, в котором этот интерфейс реализуется и переопределяются методы. В Fragment_2 есть кнопка, которая вызывает диалог Fragment_1, однако, когда на нее нажимаешь возникает ошибка. Понимаю, что дело в onAttach(Context context), но никак не соображу что именно не так. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Context - это ваша активити, а не фрагмент.

Comment: Я это понимаю, как можно в данном случае реализовать этот паттерн?

Comment: активити должна имплементить этот интерфейс и вызывать метод в другом фрагменте. Но проще сделать сеттер для addingTaskListener, при вызове диалога передать туда Fragment_2, а onAttach убрать.